# Why my site can't be found? CNAME points to AWS ELB

Tags: dns, nslookup

My nslookup

```
nslookup richardrublev.xyz
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find richardrublev.xyz: No answer
```

On Advanced DNS,I set the CNAME
[image]

I checked 3 times external IP.
How to inspect this?

Comment: @terdon I took it to be an issue with the way the OP was using `nslookup`, which is a UNIX/Linux-related issue. My answer concentrates on using `dig` to investigate issues rather than teaching how to use DNS.

Comment: @roaima so you would say it's on topic then? I admit I am not sure about it myself, I don't know enough about this sort of thing. In fact, I [just asked](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61791730#61791730) in chat whether it could be on topic. If you think it is on topic, given that you are very familiar with our scope and know more about this sort of issue, I'll take your word for it. Thanks!

Comment: @terdon it's borderline, agreed, but IMO depends on whether the focus is toolset or tutorial

Comment: @roaima It's not clear that they use `nslookup` on the system in question though. It's unclear at best.

Comment: @Kusalananda if you and Terdon agree it's OT then I'll go with that. However, I would say that it is highly probable that `nslookup` is being used on a machine running `systemd` - nothing else I've ever seen uses 127.0.0.53 as a local binding

Comment: @roaima You are absolutely correct, but the user does not actually mention that this is the same machine as `richardrublev.xyz`. This sounds more like an issue for AWS customer support, or they might ask "how do I look up the IP address of some remote system using a specific DNS server, on Linux" or the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reliable checking records in the DNS you can use `dig`. For example,

```
dig @1.1.1.1 ns richardrublev.xyz
```

which asks the nameservers at `1.1.1.1` for the Nameserver record for your domain. Among other things it returns,

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
richardrublev.xyz.      1800    IN      NS      dns1.registrar- servers.com.
richardrublev.xyz.      1800    IN      NS      dns2.registrar-servers.com.
```

which shows that the domain is registered and that its nameservers are known to exist and responding to requests.

You have no `A` record for the domain itself but you do have a TXT record, and then there is a `CNAME` record for `www` (notice that DNS also provides the A records for the target of the `CNAME`):

```
dig +noall +answer @1.1.1.1 a richardrublev.xyz

dig +noall +answer @1.1.1.1 txt richardrublev.xyz
richardrublev.xyz.      1800    IN      TXT     "v=spf1 include:spf.efwd.registrar-servers.com ~all"

dig +noall +answer @1.1.1.1 a www.richardrublev.xyz
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.richardrublev.xyz.  300     IN      CNAME   a004650fe9c3446e599ac17cd39fd74b-2077316827.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
a004650fe9c3446e599ac17cd39fd74b-2077316827.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 60 IN A 3.89.94.199
a004650fe9c3446e599ac17cd39fd74b-2077316827.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 60 IN A 107.23.178.186
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking up `richardrublev.xyz` which does indeed produce no `cname` or `a` data.

However, the `cname` which you have set up is for `www.richardrublev.xyz` which produces the following:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.31 <<>> -t a www.richardrublev.xyz
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 53273
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; COOKIE: 76e59d1c7c250e030100000062fa215e2e80a14f03a1f01d (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.richardrublev.xyz.         IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.richardrublev.xyz.  300     IN      CNAME   a004650fe9c3446e599ac17cd39fd74b-2077316827.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
a004650fe9c3446e599ac17cd39fd74b-2077316827.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 60 IN A 3.89.94.199
a004650fe9c3446e599ac17cd39fd74b-2077316827.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 60 IN A 107.23.178.186
```

You cannot setup a `cname` against a domain, since that would have to be done at the parent which would in this case be `xyz`, but you have no direct access to those servers.